Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Upgrade Black Screen at replace system.conf prompt
During my recent upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS I get a prompt to replace system.conf.  As soon as I acknowledge the prompt the system immediately goes to a black screen with no GUI and even CTRL ALT F1 will not go to the console.  I have tried completely uninstalling my Nvidia drivers prior to attempting the upgrade and going back to the "Nouveau display driver" prior to upgrading.  My video card is a GeForce GTX 1050 Ti.
Despite the above steps, every time I reach the prompt for system.conf, the second I press enter the system goes to this black screen and the update doesn't continue and the system just appears to be completely locked up.
I use nemo as my file manager and my desktop manager and now wondering if that might be the issue.  As an attempted workaround, I tried breaking to the console CTRL ALT F1 and running the upgrade completely from there.  The system still locks up at the system.conf replacement prompt even doing that.
I have bunches of other systems that I have upgraded to 24.04 with no issues.  This system is a Dell PowerEdge XPS 8930.  Any ideas?

This may help https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ask-ubuntu-is-flooded-with-failed-22-04-24-04-upgrade-issues/47701/5?u=apandada1

Anyone?  I have tried this upgrade even from a remote ssh session.  The upgrade always says "completed with errors".  The result is a system that can't "apt upgrade" because of too many errors.
